# Folders inside File Repository not possible?

Tags: directory, file-browser, impresspages

Maybe it sounds a bit like a stupid question but are there no folders inside the File Repository tool? 
It becomes pretty messy after a time for editors. 
Manually created folders (via file system) are not displayed.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no folder implementation in Repository. There are initiatives to implement tags/labels instead of folder structure.

As a quick tip. If you name your files with a logic, you can use a quick search to sort required items pretty quickly.